# find in "many to many" some values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
table users: id, first_name, ...
table dialog_members: user_id, dialog_id
table dialogs: id, ...
table messages: id, dialog_id, ...
```

How i could find Dialog by two user_id?

Example:
**dialogs**

```
1
```

**dialog_members**

```
user_id | dialog_id
1       | 1
2       | 1
1       | 2
3       | 2
...
```

I need to select dialog with user_id = 1 and user_id = 2.

Result: Dialog with id = 1

Comment: Could involve more than 2 people? If a dialog involved 3 people 1,2,3 would you want that dialog too since it contains 1,2? and could user_ID, dialog_Id be repeated in which case the distinct in the count is necessary or no and the distinct in the count on userID is not necessary?

Comment: dialog always is involved 2 people

Comment: Then below response would work. If you have more than 2 people, then the below response may pull in records you didn't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Dialog_ID 
FROM dialog_members 
WHERE user_ID in (1,2) 
GROUP BY dialog_ID 
HAVING count(Distinct user_ID) = 2
```

Limit list to just users 1,2.
Group by the dialog_ID ensure that the returned dialog_ID has a distinct user count of 2 which could only be IDS 1,2 due to the where cluase

Comment: * Note this will include dialogs involving mutliple people so long as both 1,2 user_Id's were involved.